# using assert in XML schema to do not allow a node to appear when specific condition satisfies

Tags: xml, xpath, xsd

What I should write in the assert statement if I want to express the following: in XML file whenever an A node appears, then either a B node or a C node or both should appear such that A\@OID eq B\@OID and A\@OID eq C\@OID. Basically, regarding the provided XML, the last A node that has OID=HHH should not appear.

The following is the XML Schema document:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">-->
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" vc:minVersion="1.1">
 <xs:element name="Document">
  <xs:complexType>
   <xs:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">
    <xs:element ref="A" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    <xs:element ref="B" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    <xs:element ref="C" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
   </xs:sequence>
   <xs:assert test="every $a in A, $b in B[@OID eq $a/@OID] satisfies $a/@A_Membership_Degree ge $b/@B_Membership_Degree"/>
   <xs:assert test="every $a in A, $c in C[@OID eq $a/@OID] satisfies $a/@A_Membership_Degree ge $c/@C_Membership_Degree"/>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:key name="aKey">
   <xs:selector xpath="A"/>
   <xs:field xpath="@OID"/>
  </xs:key>
  <xs:key name="bKey">
   <xs:selector xpath="B"/>
   <xs:field xpath="@OID"/>
  </xs:key>
  <xs:key name="cKey">
   <xs:selector xpath="C"/>
   <xs:field xpath="@OID"/>
  </xs:key>
  <xs:keyref name="aKeyRef" refer="aKey">
   <xs:selector xpath="./B"/>
   <xs:field xpath="@OID"/>
  </xs:keyref>
  <xs:keyref name="aKeyRef1" refer="aKey">
   <xs:selector xpath="./C"/>
   <xs:field xpath="@OID"/>
  </xs:keyref>
 </xs:element>
 <xs:element name="A" type="Atype"/>
 <xs:complexType name="Atype">
  <xs:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
   <xs:element name="A1" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
   <xs:element name="A2" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
  </xs:sequence>
  <xs:attribute name="OID" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
  <xs:attribute name="A_Membership_Degree" type="FuzzyValue" use="optional"/>
 </xs:complexType>
 <xs:element name="B" type="Btype"/>
 <xs:complexType name="Btype">
  <xs:sequence>
   <xs:element name="B1" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
   <xs:element name="B2" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
  </xs:sequence>
  <xs:attribute name="OID" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
  <xs:attribute name="B_Membership_Degree" type="FuzzyValue" use="optional"/>
 </xs:complexType>
 <xs:element name="C" type="Ctype"/>
 <xs:complexType name="Ctype">
  <xs:sequence>
   <xs:element name="C1" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
   <xs:element name="C2" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
  </xs:sequence>
  <xs:attribute name="OID" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
  <xs:attribute name="C_Membership_Degree" type="FuzzyValue" use="required"/>
 </xs:complexType>
 <xs:simpleType name="FuzzyValue">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:decimal">
   <xs:minInclusive value="0"/>
   <xs:maxInclusive value="1"/>
  </xs:restriction>
 </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

The following XML Document, should not be valid because the last A node that has OID=HHH should not appear.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="gen.xsd">
<A OID="AA" A_Membership_Degree="0.7" >
  <A1>X1</A1>
  <A2>D1</A2>
 </A>
 <B OID="AA" B_Membership_Degree="0.6" >
  <B1>G1</B1>
  <B2>F1</B2>
 </B>
  <C  OID="AA" C_Membership_Degree="0.3" >
  <C1>G2</C1>
  <C2>F2</C2>
 </C>
 
<A OID="AAA" A_Membership_Degree="0.8"  >
  <A1>X2</A1>
  <A2>D2</A2>
 </A>
  <B OID="AAA" B_Membership_Degree="0.2"  >
  <B1>G3</B1>
  <B2>F3</B2>
 </B>   
 <A OID="HHH" A_Membership_Degree="0.8" >
  <A1>X11</A1>
  <A2>D11</A2>
 </A>

</Document>
```

Thanks very much for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> in XML file whenever an A node appears, then either a B node or a C node or both should appear such that A\@OID eq B\@OID and A\@OID eq C\@OID.

Sounds to me like

```
<xs:assert test="every $a in A satisfies 
  (exists(B[@OID eq $a/@OID]) or exists(C[@OID eq $a/@OID]))"/>
```

which could be shortened to

```
<xs:assert test="every $a in A satisfies (B|C)[@OID eq $a/@OID]"/>
```